# How can I check if an object is in the CurrentCamera Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have defined a variable for an object in my code and I want to check if it is in the current players camera. Can anyone advise?
Thanks!

Comment: this is a matter of reading the Roblox manual and maybe some basic linar algebra. you should at least show some attempt to solve the problem. this is not a coding service. please read [ask]

Comment: It's a good question which /sounds/ simple enough! Post some of your code and tell us what you've tried so far. At least post code you've got up to that refers to the camera, the the object you want to test, and in what context the code is running. That gives commenters somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Please next time making an answer to include your current code so we can help you understand better!

```
local Object = GetObject -- Place the object's path under a variable.

if Object.Parent == workspace.Camera then -- Right now, we're getting the Object's part and then comparing it to workspace.Camera. If this comes back as true, the function runs. If not, it won't run.
    -- Do something
end
```